# Is it possible to detect inside smart contract if a nft was sold through opensea?

Tags: erc-721, opensea

Is it possible to detect inside contract that the nft was sold through opensea or that it was a simple transfer? Are there any methods without oracles?

Answer (score 1):

A quick idea.

When calling `transferFrom`, there are 3 variables of interest: `msg.sender`, `_from` and `_to`.

If `_from == msg.sender` or `_to == msg.sender`, you can assume it is a simple transfer.

If they are different, you can assume that `msg.sender` is a third-party that is handling the transfer on behalf of them. Perhaps Opensea.